# postgresql to_tsquery() with PDO's prepared statement

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

If write directly

```
$sql = "... to_tsquery( 'word_1 | word_2' )";
```

Works, but how to use this syntax with PDO's prepared statement?

What is right syntax for this:

```
$sql = " ... to_tsquery( :word_1 | :word_2 ) "; //this is incorrect

$sth = $db->prepare( $sql );
$sth->execute(
    array( ':word_1'=>"word_1",  ':word_2'=>"word_2" )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
denis=# select to_tsquery('(foo | bar) & baz');
        to_tsquery         
---------------------------
 ( 'foo' | 'bar' ) & 'baz'
(1 row)

denis=# select (to_tsquery('foo') || to_tsquery('bar')) && to_tsquery('baz');
         ?column?          
---------------------------
 ( 'foo' | 'bar' ) & 'baz'
(1 row)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @shapeshifter: by highlighting the arithmetics needed, perhaps? For instance, not `to_tsquery( :word_1 | :word_2 )` but indeed `to_tsquery( :word_1 ) || to_tsquery( :word_2 )`...